# Load testing logged in routes in phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, load-testing

I'm trying to do load testing for routes that require logging in.

I was previously using https://artillery.io/docs/index.html for logged out routes which worked fine. For logged in routes, I tried calling `beforeRequest` with a function to set the request headers & body.

`config:
  target: "https://www.mywebsite.com/"
  phases:
    - duration: 60
      arrivalRate: 50
  processor: "test.js"
scenarios:
  - flow:
    - post:
        url: "/login"
        beforeRequest: "setReqBody"`

and my beforeRequest looked like this:

`function setReqBody(requestParams, context, ee, next) {
   requestParams.body = {'email': 'user@mail.com', 'password': 'password', '_csrf_token': window.csrfToken}
   return next();
}`

I am getting an error that `window` is undefined.

I had a look around to see if there was anything else I could use for load testing phoenix, but didn't have much luck. Is there any other way I can log in & test those routes? Or other dependencies/libraries I can use in order to do this?

Comment: it could be worth asking @hassy-veldstra (creator of Artillery) directly for help on this...

Answer (score 4):

The issue is that `window` is not defined in the context that the `beforeRequest` function runs in (as the code is not running in a browser).

If the CSRF token is included somewhere in the DOM/HTML of the login page, you can grab it first and then include it in the POST request. For example, if the login form had a hidden input containing the CSRF token with `name` attribute =`csrfToken`:

```
scenarios:
  - flow:

    # Get the login page and grab the CSRF token
    - get:
        url: "/login"
        capture:
          selector: "input[name='csrf_token']"
          attr: "value"
          as: "csrfToken"

    # Useful for debugging: check that we used the right selector:
    - log: "Extracted CSRF token: {{ csrfToken }}"

    # Now send a login request:
    - post:
        url: "/login"
        form:
          email: "user@mail.com"
          password: "password123"
          _csrf_token: "{{ csrfToken }}"

    # The session cookie will be remembered and reused automatically by
    # Artillery from this point onwards.
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/), it has:

- [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler to mimic HTTP Requests
- [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) to set required HTTP Request headers, i.e. [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type)
- a number of [Post Processors](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) for extracting "interesting" fields from response message, code, data, headers, etc.
- [HTML Reporting Dashboard](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) to visualize load test results

See [REST API Testing - How to Do it Right](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/rest-api-testing-how-to-do-it-right) for details.